# Creating library in TwinCAT 3

Tags: plc, twincat

I have made some "standard" functionblocks that I would like to add to a new library that I can include when making a new project, but for the sake of me I can't figure out how to do it.

On Beckhoffs website it says to create a new library-project from the library template. I don't have that template though, and I just reinstalled TC3 with everything included.

So my question is:
What is the procedure to make a new library in TC3, and how do I add functions to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out.
If you right click on a project under "PLC" in the solution explorer, you get the option to save as a library.

[image]

Also, you don't create a library project from a template when you create a new project, as I initially thought. You create an "Empty PLC project" when you add a new item to the PLC folder in an existing project.